# How to tween (with ease out) a movie clip using only Action Script 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2, movieclip, tween

I would like to tween a movieclip (with ease out) using purely action script 2.0.  Does anyone know where to find any resources on this or could point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to import

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;
```

and then use the command

```
 new Tween(yourMovieClip, "_alpha", Regular.easeOut, 40, 100, 1, true);
```

so to speak

```
// to tween over a period of time:
new Tween(movieclip, "property", easing-type, start-value, stop-value, #seconds, true);

// to tween over a number of frames:
new Tween(movieclip, "property", easing-type, start-value, stop-value, #frames, false);
```

you can read the [tween class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#Tween%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Although the mx.transitions.Tween class will get you there, I recommend the [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) library. As the docs say, "it is not tied to specific properties of built-in Classes such as MovieClips or TextFields." Also they have all kinds of cool easing-type curves and so forth.

The examples are awesome and you will able to bring your knowledge forward to AS3 and even Javascript.

Also, I cannot remember what other stuff it does, but I remember tossing out the Tween class on a project about a year ago due to some limits it had, or perhaps because it was cumbersome (or impossible?) to have Tweens fire other Tweens.

Comment: I prefer the TweenLite/TweenMax libraries as they are faster, smaller and leave more freedom, and I like the API a bit more